# How can I pass objects as parameter using IDL

Tags: java, corba, idl

I am new to idl, corba. I have a java code I would like to distribute by using one of it's methods and this method requires an object from another class as a parameter. Please how do I specify this scenario using idl.

```
public void receive(Receiver rec, Message msg) {
    rec.treatMessage(msg);
}
```

This is what i tried defining as my idl

```
module talk {
  struct Message{
    string msg;
    double time;
  };
  typedef Received Receiver;
  interface Contract{
    void receive(in Receiver rec, in Message msg);
  };
};
```

Each time I run this against idlj I keep getting "Received" is an undeclared type. 
Please how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare an interface of type Receiver with the operation treatMessage just as you declared an interface of type Contract with operation receive. Or do

```
module talk {
  struct Message{
    string msg;
    double time;
  };
  interface Receiver{
    void receive(in Message msg);
  };
};
```

Comment: Won't that mean that I will be granting remote access to the Receiver class if I declare it as an interface? If yes I wouldn't want this to happen

Comment: Yes, at the moment you declare Receiver as interface you can access it remotely.

Comment: I would not want that to happen in this case.

Comment: One option is to make it a valuetype which looks like a cross between an interface and a struct, you can move its value from one system to another, but slightly more complex to use. Maybe take a step back and first describe what your requirements really are.

Comment: I looked into valuetype and it seems to be complex for a beginner like me. Then I stumbled on Object in idl which maps to org.omg.CORBA.Object in java. I don't know if I am on the right track with this but it seems to be worth taking a look at.